# Git: what's the best practice for DEV-QA-PROD cycle with A/B testing?

Tags: git

We've just moved to Git.
We have a live product with millions of users. Currently, we branch from master for every feature and when the work is done we release it to QA for testing. Once approved, it goes live for A/B testing @ 10% vs. the current running version in PROD (10% also).
If everything goes well we publish on 50% and then 100%.

The problems starts when:

1. Until version goes to 100% it takes few days. Meanwhile, we work on
   different features and they all branched from master so when we want
   to publish the next release for A/B testing, the base version is
   different (master which not including the last release). We can
   always pull the latest before releasing to QA but we don't want to
   wait for the version to go 100%, it takes time and now QA will have
   to test everything again since it's a different release.
2. If we decide to branch from the latest release and not from the
   master - sometimes the latest release could be rejected and deleted
   and the we need to lose all the latest version commits and go back
   to origin.

I guess there are good practices for this cycle when waiting for A/B testing results, would love to read about them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this schema: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

You are looking for "release branches" - branch which is created at the time project goes to QA. This creates place where no new features are added, only bugs are fixed.

I use this schema for last two years on my project and it's working great.

All development is in DEV branch - new features are branches based on DEV. When you decide to release new version of software, you merge feature branches into DEV and create new branch for release. This release branch is place where bugs are fixed, development goes on in DEV branch.

You can merge release branch to DEV branch regularly to include bugfixes to development version. When you decide to publish new version, then merge release branch to DEV to preserve all bugfixes and merge release branch to master.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this schema but still couldn't figure how this might help in my case. 
Let's say that I create the DEV, release and feature branch. Now I've finished working on a feature and release to QA. By the time that the release is approved, I already created a new branch which doesn't include the changes that were released to QA. Only when the latest release is approved and go 100% to PROD, only then it will be tested in PROD and therefor it must include the previous release.
It means that all the QA work that has been done is meaningless..

Thanks.

Comment: Response updated, hope this is more clear. Please accept the answer.